# How to get this captcha image link?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webbrowser-control, captcha

I need to show this captcha image ( http://www3.dataprev.gov.br/cws/contexto/hiscre/index.html ) in a C# application, but I can't get it to work! I have no ideia how to get the captcha link, this link ( http://www3.dataprev.gov.br/cws/bin/dtpv.asp ) doesn't work... Any Ideas?

Comment: I tried to go to the URL and the CAPTCHA never fully loads. Are you trying to determine what DOM element the CAPTCHA is in and then get the content for the element?

Comment: Actualy I dont know what I have to do, I just need to find out how to get the image using the c# WebBroser control and put it on a PictureBox.

Comment: Well are you able to determine what DOM element the CAPTCHA is being displayed within? Without that, it is going to be impossible to figure out how to "grab" the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Fiddler scrren capture]

The problem is that this site apparently does not let you load the same captcha twice. I was able to make the captcha appear by intercepting the request in fiddler and changing the values after the "=" in Cookie http header to a random value.

For example,

```
Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDASDCDQBE=IOMFMDMCOBNECLCLEAIFJPEK; ASPSESSIONIDASCDBRAD=AAEFMDMCKLOAMDIAJPGNNNDG

Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDASDCDQBE=IOMFMDMCOBNECLCLEAIFJPEL; ASPSESSIONIDASCDBRAD=AAEFMDMCKLOAMDIAJPGNNNDH
```

Now you have to somehow match the captcha to the session in order for it to be valid, but this should already point ou in the right direction.

Comment: @Vinicius How did it go?

Comment: I was able to get make a httpwebrequest and got a response, just not the right one yet. I'm trying to figure out which headers I have to send in the request.

Comment: Yay I did it! HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www3.dataprev.gov.br/cws/bin/dtpv.asp");
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;

Answer (score 0):

It looks like someone else has already tried to do this.

It's in Python but I think you should take a look [**here**](http://pastebin.com/im2UVeSG) and see  if something similar works for you.